# Where is the best place to declare variables that are only used in a limited scope?

Tags: c++, variable-declaration

I am trying to optimize a program in C++ I have implemented and a question came in mind... 
Where should I declare a variable if I have a repetitive structure using it?

For example:

```
//1-> int sum;
int matrix[10][10];

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    //1-> sum=0;
    //2-> int sum=0;
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        sum += matrix[i][j];

    printf("%d ", sum);
}
```

So which is better/recommended? Should I declare it at the beginning //->1 outside of the repetitive structure or it is fine if is redeclared //->2 at each iteration? 
My guess is that declaration takes a very small time (milliseconds or less) but if you redeclare it in a repetitive structure big enough (or inside multiple structures) each redeclaration will add up to some extra seconds.

Comment: use whichever is most readable(=understandable). Rule of thumb is: declare as close as possible to point of use. Don't optimise without benchmarking. And then benchmark again!

Comment: In this case, neither. Use `std::accumulate` to compute your sums (and probably use `std::cout` instead of `printf` to display them).

Comment: It's a little odd to be concerned about potential loss of CPU cycles when you have a big dirty `printf` in your loop.

Comment: Allocating storage on the stack takes a single operation (you adjust the stack pointer) and the compiler tries to aggregate your variable sizes to keep it to a single adjustment. Initializing data is expensive. E.g. putting `char str[1024] = "0";` (see http://ideone.com/WmLtQp -- this initialization is expensive) or `std::vector<int> vec; vec.reserve(100000);` inside a loop will rack up the cost if the compiler finds a case in which the variable is used before being assigned to elsewhere in your loop.

Answer (score 5):

For an `int` it just doesn't matter. For a type with a non-trivial constructor or destructor, under scheme 2 it would be constructed and destroyed each time through the outer loop, and that would be potentially time-consuming.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter. The stack (reserved space in memory) is allocated all together in the beginning of the function/method. If it's an object, the contructor and destructor will be called somewhere in the scope of your loop. But for elemental types, there's absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already stated, it mostly doesn't matter for an `int`.

There are only two things to concern yourself with here:

1. Readability
2. Scope

If the `int` is declared right before the `for` loop rather than as the first line of the `for` loop, readability is probably about the same.  Plus, many compiler's will have a shortcut for jumping straight to a declaration.

As for Scope, if you don't need the variable outside of the loop, putting it inside helps make sure you don't accidentally use it outside the loop in any way.  If you do need it outside the loop, you really don't have much choice.

---

A note on my personal preference which combines both scope and readability issues, when I write code, I prefer having EVERY variable I will use in a given scope declared at the beginning of that scope.  Any variable I use in `main` is declared at the top of `main`.  Any variable used in a function is declared at the top of that function.  Any variable used in a loop is declared at the top of that loop.  Any variable used in a `if` statement is declared at the top of that `if` statement.  I personally make very few exceptions.  So in your case, if the `scope` of `sum` is limited purely to your `for` loop, I'd declare it as the first variable of the `for` loop.  If `sum` needs scope outside of the loop, I'd declare it at the top of whatever function you're in and give it a far more descriptive name.

Comment: I am having a similar conversation with a co-worker. My memory of using MISRA at a previous company is that all variables must be declared not just at start of scope but start of function. Certainly, seeing this guy's code with declarations liberally scattered throughout gives me a really uncomfortable feeling. Even just putting them at start of scope is so much better.